# Highstock/Highchart Y axis label names breaking on multiple lines in timeseries chart

Tags: highcharts, angular2-highcharts

[image: Time series chart]

[![enter image description here]

I have this chart plotted and as we can see the y axis label names are appearing in multiple lines. There are 3 columns selected in Y AXIS. Is there a way where we can display them each in one line

Answer (score 0):

You can set `width` style for y-axis title and position it in the `render` event callback. For example:

```
  chart: {
    height: 230,
    events: {
      render: function() {
        this.yAxis[0].axisTitle.attr({
          y: 115
        });
      }
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: '30 Days Active Users 60 Days Active Users 90 Days Active Users',
      style: {
        width: 230
      }
    },
    opposite: false
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/q1sykznu/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.title